# command line equivalent to saving a website using right click save webpage

Tags: linux, command-line

On mozilla firefox on centos if I right click on a website I can save the webpage by clicking "save page as" in the menu shown below:

[image]

is there a way to also do this using command line?

I noticed that when I save the website from the browser I get more details in the output file than when just doing curl and wget.  How can I get those extra details including links to certain files on the website through using a command line interface like wget and curl?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how to do this with `curl`, but I do not doubt there is an equivalent set of options for it.

Using `wget`, the following should be pluggable for downloading a specific page and related assets:

```
wget --adjust-extension --span-hosts --convert-links --backup-converted \
     --no-directories --timestamping --page-requisites \
     --directory-prefix=thepageslug \
     https://example.com/page/of/interest
```

https://gist.github.com/dannguyen/03a10e850656577cfb57

Answer (score 0):

Both wget and curl can do what you want. Both commands allow you to specify a output file name like below.

```
wget -O <filename> <your_url>


curl -O <filename> <your_url>
```

Comment: I noticed that when I save the website from the browser I get more details in the output file than when just doing curl and wget. How can I get those extra details including links to certain files on the website through using a command line interface like wget and curl?